# How can I make vuefire show loading screen?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuefire

As title
Vuefire can auto get data from firebase database, but it needs some loading time.
So I want to display some css animation before data being fetched, is there any event can I $watch when it successed

Comment: try using [vue-spinner](http://greyby.github.io/vue-spinner/) if check data v-show

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this multiple ways.
`Vuefire` has `readyCallback` out of the box which is callback called when the data is fetched (ready).

Here it is:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: function() {
    return {
       loaded: false
    }
  }
  firebase: {
    // simple syntax, bind as an array by default
    anArray: db.ref('url/to/my/collection'),
    // can also bind to a query
    // anArray: db.ref('url/to/my/collection').limitToLast(25)
    // full syntax
    anObject: {
      source: db.ref('url/to/my/object'),
      // optionally bind as an object
      asObject: true,
      // optionally provide the cancelCallback
      cancelCallback: function () {},
      // this is called once the data has been retrieved from firebase
      readyCallback: function () {
         this.loaded = true // NOTE THIS LINE
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 4):

The `readyCallback` approach in the other answer didn't work for me. I got an error `document.onSnapshot is not a function`.

Instead, I used the [binding approach](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/vuefire/binding-subscriptions.html#programmatic-binding) to set a flag when loading is complete.

```js
<script>
    // ...

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                data: [],
                loaded: false,
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.$bind('data', firebase.firestore().collection('someDocRef'))
                .then(() => this.loaded = true);
        },
    }
</script>
```

Then my template can have conditionally-rendered loading screens:

```
<template>
    <template v-if="!loaded">
        <p>Loading...</p>
    </template>

    <template v-if="loaded">
        <!-- Display data here -->
    </template>
</template>
```

Comment: This works for me and should be ticked as the answer instead.
Although, a little change in my code compared to this answer

 mounted() {
    this.$bind("data", db.collection("documents")).then(
      () => (this.loaded = true)
    );
  }

Instead of `firebase.firestore`, I used  `db.collections...` which is what I exported from my firebase config file.